# In drupal, I want to align every product on same Line in bootstrap theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-9, drupal-themes

I am developing an E-commerce site for that I am using Bootstrap theme & Accordion module. I have added taxonomy for all Categories with their respective sub categories. After that I have added the sample contents for them. So my issue is in my frontend they are not in the same line one product is up and other product is down which is not looking good to see.

My frontend looks like this:

[image]

My view for this:

[image]

Comment: The view and bootstrap working just fine, what you have to do is to adjust you image heights. Look up on you bootstrap they all have a perfect square grid.

Comment: Just pull down your title to the down or make a div looks the same as a tallest one  and you will be good to go.